# Best way to connect Django Query results to Chart.js charts?

Tags: python, django, chart.js

Can someone advise what is the cleanest/easyest way to connect my query to the Data/Label part of chart.js script?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can simply pass the data queryset to template context.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can do this in your `views.py`:

```
# inside views.py

from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render

class YourView(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      context = {} # <- you can add whatever you want in here
      # some code...
      return render(request, "path/to/js/file", context, content_type="text/javascript")
```

Inside your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path("data/js", views.YourView.as_view(), name="somejs"),
   # and other urls...
]
```

Inside your template (html file)

```
<!-- this is just an example -->
<div>
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'somejs' %}"></script>
<div/>
```

Inside your js file, you can do some javascript.

```
var chart = document.getElementById("myChart");

"{{some_context}}" // you can access to the context

{% if some_context %}
   // do something 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to implement this today and tomorrow. I wil give you an update. Have a nice day!

Comment: This does not seem to work, sorry